# Pass Variable to AndroidViewModel

Tags: android, json, kotlin, viewmodel

I'm struggling with a ViewModel issue, I'm quite new to them.

I need to be able to access a Json file in my assets folder, so I'm using androidViewModel.
But I also need to pass a category into the viewModel, so I can filter the json file by that category.

What I've tried so far.
building a viewModeFactory
Creating a ResourcesProvider
creating a seperate viewModel for each category

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Here's my current viewModel

```
class GuideViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val _name = MutableLiveData<String>()

    val name: LiveData<String>
        get() = _name
    private val _difficulty = MutableLiveData(3)
    val difficulty: LiveData<Int>
        get() = _difficulty
    private val _date = MutableLiveData<Long>(3010)
    val date: LiveData<Long>
        get() = _date
    private val _graphic = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val graphic: LiveData<String>
        get() = _graphic

    private var brewerDetails: MutableLiveData<MovieObject>? = null

    fun getDetails(CurrentMovie: String): MutableLiveData<MovieObject> {
            brewerDetails = MutableLiveData<MovieObject>()
            loadJsonData(CurrentMovie)
            return brewerDetails as MutableLiveData<MovieObject>
    }

    private fun loadJsonData(CurrentMovie: String) {
        var CurrentMovieObject = MovieObject()

        try {
            val jsonString = loadJsonDataFromFile()
            val json = JSONObject(jsonString)
            val jsonBrewers = json.getJSONArray("movies")

            for (index in 0 until jsonBrewers.length()) {
                if (jsonBrewers.getJSONObject(index).getString(KEY_NAME) == "VARIABLE") { << need to pass a variable into viewModel somehow
                    val name = jsonBrewers.getJSONObject(index).getString(KEY_NAME)
                    val difficulty = jsonBrewers.getJSONObject(index).getInt(KEY_DIFFICULTY)
                    val date = jsonBrewers.getJSONObject(index).getLong(KEY_DATE)
                    val graphic = jsonBrewers.getJSONObject(index).getString(KEY_GRAPHIC)
                    _name.value = name
                    _difficulty.value = difficulty
                    _date.value = date
                    _graphic.value = graphic
                }
            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
        }
    }

    private fun loadJsonDataFromFile(): String {
        var json = ""

        try {
            val input = getApplication<Application>().assets.open("movies.json") << need application to open the json file
            val size = input.available()
            val buffer = ByteArray(size)
            input.read(buffer)
            input.close()
            json = buffer.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return json
    }
}
```

Comment: "But I also need to pass a category into the viewModel, so I can filter the json file by that category" - do you want to do that at point of instantiation as a constructor parameter or by a function of the class called by the client i.e `viewModel.filterBy(category : CategoryType) { .. do work and update observed movie live data list }`? What is stopping you doing either? Also all your code around json really belongs in some sort of repository (Model part of MVVM) that your viewmodel depends on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will have a look at the repository, I don't have a ton of data, 6 categories, with 8 or so attributes so I didnt think I needed a repo. AndroidViewModel only takes one constructor, Application, which is why I can't pass the category on instantiation. I've tried functions in the viewModel, but I'll give it another go.

Comment: "AndroidViewModel only takes one constructor, Application, which is why I can't pass the category on instantiation." - that's a constraint of the super type, it has no default constructor. As you are sub-classing it, with a custom `ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory` you can do what you want.  It seems that really you just need one `AndroidViewModel` that allows for the category/filter to be updated on the same dataset by the client, as described in my first comment.

Comment: I got it working using your suggestion, viewModel.getDetails(param1). Thanks for your help, I got stuck on that for quite a while.